# .NET How to extract embedded image from email message?

Tags: .net, image, email, extract, embedded-resource

Hello I'm working on a project in .NET 1.1 and I have a requirement to extract (and save it somewhere) embedded image from emails that I'm receiving.

Can someone give me a clue on where to start?

thank you

Comment: from outlook? web mail? or something else?

Comment: How are you receiving the emails ? Using Outlook ? By using a POP3 or IMAP component ? something else ?

Comment: Well, yes we are using POP3, third party component for retrieving emails from the email server. It's OpenPOP.net component...

Comment: Almost similar SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/440356/extracting-embedded-images-from-outlook-email

Answer (score 2):

The email downloaded from the POP server will be in text format, you will have to parse the whole email, and find all the `<img />` tags having the `src` attribute set to `cid:*`

E.g.

```
<img src='cid:006901c6d391$dee64770$6c822ecf@Z2LC74Q' />
```

The format of an email containing the embedded image will be as follows -

```
From: foo1atbar.net 
To: foo2atbar.net 
Subject: A simple example 
Mime-Version: 1.0 
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="boundary-example"; type="text/html" 

--boundary-example 
Content-Type: text/html; charset="US-ASCII" 

... text of the HTML document, which might contain a URI 
referencing a resource in another body part, for example 
through a statement such as: 
<IMG SRC="cid:foo4atfoo1atbar.net" ALT="IETF logo"> 
...snip...
Content-Location: CID:somethingatelse ;this header is disregarded 
Content-ID: <006901c6d391$dee64770$6c822ecf@Z2LC74Q>
Content-Type: IMAGE/GIF 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: BASE64 

R0lGODlhGAGgAPEAAP/////ZRaCgoAAAACH+PUNv 
cHlyaWdodCAoQykgMTk5LiBVbmF1dGhvcml6ZWQgZHV 
wbGljYXRpb24gcHJvaGliaXRlZC4A etc... 

...snip...
```

If you take a look at the footer, it contains a BASE64 encoded version of your image. You can extract the the BASE64 string, convert it to bytes based on the email character set, and save it to a file (you can get the file extension based on the Content-Type). Tada, done!

Hope you've got an idea of how to do it!

### EDIT

I also found a similary question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/440356/extracting-embedded-images-from-outlook-email). He's using CDO (Collaboration Data Objects).